# Protected multilib versions: openssl

Tags: centos, openssl

I'm running on Centos 6.2 x86_64

Trying to install ruby 2.1.2

```
---> Package libselinux-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.94-5.2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsepol-devel >= 2.0.32-1 for package: libselinux-devel-2.0.94-5.2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(libsepol) for package: libselinux-devel-2.0.94-5.2.el6.x86_64
---> Package zlib.i686 0:1.2.3-29.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package keyutils-libs.i686 0:1.4-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libselinux.i686 0:2.0.94-5.2.el6 will be installed
---> Package libsepol-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.41-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.12.9-11.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Protected multilib versions: openssl-1.0.0-20.el6.i686 != openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

If I get the installed packages:

```
[root@test tmp]# rpm -qa | grep openssl
openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64
openssl098e-0.9.8e-17.el6.centos.x86_64
```

I didn't see that `openssl-1.0.0-20.el6.i686`

How can I remove it?

Comment: You should upgrade your OS.  CentOS-6 went end-of-life a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

The error means you are trying to install a different version for one architecture than you have installed for the other. The solution is to upgrade the current version of your package to the version that will be installed for the other architecture. In your case, that would mean downgrade `openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64` to `openssl-1.0.0-20.el6.x86_64` then try the command again, but that is not optimal. Instead, you might have some repos disabled that you need to enable to get the right version of the package for both architectures.